# Having trouble with asp.net and Java HttpComponents post request

Tags: java, asp.net, session, post, apache-httpcomponents

I have a particular problem where an .aspx site won't generate a session ID cookie with a post request done with HttpComponents.

The website is the login for my school's online schedule viewer. https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/22/login.aspx
Alternatively I posted the HTML to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/nMhxfgjL

(Brugernavn is username and adgangskode is password)

I identified the names of the input fields to be m$Content$username2 and m$Content$password2

My code looks like this:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/22/login.aspx");

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
    if (entity != null) {
        entity.consumeContent();
    }

    System.out.println("Initial set of cookies:");
    List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("None");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
        }
    }

    HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://www.lectio.dk/lectio/22/login.aspx");

    List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m$Content$username2", "blabla")); //set your own username
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("m$Content$password2", "blabla")); //set your own password

    httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

    response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
    entity = response.getEntity();

    System.out.println("Login form get: " + response.getStatusLine());
    if (entity != null) {
        entity.consumeContent();
    }

    System.out.println("Post logon cookies:");
    cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
    if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("None");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
        }
    }
```

For obvious reasons I didn't include my username and password.

The output I get from running it is

> Login form get: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Initial set of cookies:
>
> [version: 0][name: lecmobile][value: 0][domain: www.lectio.dk][path: /][expiry: Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 CET 2029]
>
> [version: 0][name: lectiogsc][value: 831859d3-370c-a582-340d-0377177bfcae][domain: www.lectio.dk][path:
>   /][expiry: Sat Jan 01 00:59:59 CET 10000]
>
> Login form get: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Post logon cookies:
>
> [version: 0][name: lecmobile][value: 0][domain: www.lectio.dk][path: /][expiry: Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 CET 2029]
>
> [version: 0][name: lectiogsc][value: 831859d3-370c-a582-340d-0377177bfcae][domain: www.lectio.dk][path:
>   /][expiry: Sat Jan 01 00:59:59 CET 10000]

The only cookie that matters is the one called "ASP.NET_SessionId". Apparently you won't get this, at least not with a value, until you log in.

Also, I could imagine that the HTTP response wouldn't be 200, as you are redirected upon successful login...

Would love any help :)

Thanks
Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Not getting session cookie might be a server configuration issue.

Comment: Afraid not. It's an issue with the post request. If I manually log in I will get the session cookie.

Comment: Just for a note: Session cookie is not necessarily tied with login. If session management is enabled, response from first request may have session cookie.

Comment: I know, but it is in this case, as I can see from testing with the browser :)